# AOT: how to specify index column order when updating an existing index?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

In AOT, when I create a new index, and I want the key columns in a specific order, I understand I have to add them in the reverse order.  ie if I want key column order col1, col2, col3, then when adding a new column to the index, I have to add columns in reverse order ie: col3, col2, col1.

However if I have to edit an existing index and add a new key column, AOT adds the column to the front of the key.  If I want this new key column as the last column, or in the middle, how does one go about doing that?  Do I need to create a new index in AOT, then drop the existing index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select field in the index and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to move it up or down.

See [Shortcut Keys: AOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa623612.aspx) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of the an existing index either by using mouse drag and drop or by marking the field then moving it up or down using the Alt-arrow up or down.

The same can be applied anywhere in the AOT where order is relevant, say form controls etc.

Also see [this blog](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/exploreax/archive/2015/05/19/14-using-alt-up-down-to-rearrange-the-order-of-elements-in-the-aot).

Comment: I got the alt up/down keys to work, thanks, but the mouse drag/drop doesn't work for me at all, can you clarify how you do it?